# I cannot create a controller in ruby on rails. All my gems are not loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

```
rails g controller welcome index

C:/Program Files/Ruby.../rubygems/dependency.rb:247: amongst [actionmailer
3.2.3,actionpack...(all my rubygems listed here)] (Gem::LoadError) 
    from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.3.../rubygems/dependecney.rb:256:in 'to_spec' 
    from C:/Program Files/ruby-1.9.3.../rubygems.rb:1231: in 'gem' 
    from C:/RailsInstasller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails:18:in '<main>'
```

Im a beginner to Ruby on Rails, trying to make my first project.
I am following http://railsinstaller.org, and right now when I type in the first line, the next 5 lines are the error that appears.

Im wondering if the problem might be the two different Ruby's I seem to have (in program files and rails installer?).
I looked through some other posts and couldn't find anything quite like this, i tried `gem install bundler`, but that didn't do anything.
If you know what my problem is or how to fix it, i would appreciate it

Comment: can you try "bundle exec rails g controller welcome index"... and please output the entire error message.

Comment: ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)

Answer (score 1):

do `$ bundle install` at the command line at the root (top directory) of your project.

Your efforts with bundler indicate installing it but not actually running it for your project.

Comment: no, now where I try to make the controller it just lists each gem twice